# Maximum Likelihood for shifted Geometric Distribution

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, order-statistics, geometric-distribution

Really struggling with this please help.

Find MLE for p and c

\begin{equation}
\ {f}(x,p,c) = (1-p)^{x-c}p
\end{equation}

x=c,c+1,c+2,.....

p is between 0 and 1

c is element of the integers

I am more interested in the mle for c

For the mle of p is it fine to just take the derivative of the log likelihood function.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework problem, and if so, please add the `homework` or `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

$L = \prod_i (1-p)^{x_i-c} p$

To maximize the above we work with the log-likelihood:

$LL = \sum_i \Big( (x_i-c) \log(1-p) + \log(p) \Big)$

Comment: I worked with the Likelihood function and I know taking derivative w.r.t c wont work because c is an integer and it is in the support of x. So we have to use order stats. Now the exponent needs to be as small is possible to get the maximum likelihood function. That means c needs be as large as possible. Now I dont know whether to choose the 1st odered stat of x or the nth ordered stat

Comment: Sure, you cannot use calculus. What value of $c$ will maximize the log likelihood? Keeping in mind the restrictions that $x_i \ge c$ for $i=1,2, ..n$. You are on the right track. Why don't you try out a few values for $x_i$ and check which one you should pick- 1st order or nth order.

Comment: We want the exponent to be as small as possible so would we choose the 1st order

Comment: If we chose c= nth order stat that would mean c is bigger than than 1st 2nd 3rd... order stats which is not possible because of the restriction. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Did you try *drawing a picture* of the likelihood or the log likelihood?

Comment: Yes it is an increasing fuction w.r.t c. As c increases the exponent gers smaller and since $o<1-p<1$ the smallest exponent will give the largest value. If I choose c = $x_(n)$ then wont that contridict the support for c

Comment: Is my thinking correct for this?