# Challenging Likelihood Ratio Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, maximum-likelihood, likelihood-ratio

Derive Likelihood Ratio Test of size $\alpha$. H$_0$: $\theta=\theta_0$  H$_1$:$\theta \neq \theta_0$

\begin{equation}
{f}(x,\theta , c) = \theta(x-c)^{\theta-1}  \ {c<x<c+1}
\end{equation}

I am having trouble with the mle for c. We have to use order stats and I am not sure which is the correct one to use

Comment: The methods outlined in the answer to [your previous question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73712/maximum-likelihood-for-shifted-geometric-distribution) will work well here, too.

Comment: I get $L(\theta , c) = \theta^n \Pi(x_i -c)^{\theta -1}$. I know we need to use order stats and I get $x_(i)-1 < c < x_(i)$ I dont know where to go from there

Comment: Maximize $\log(L),$ just as the answer in the other question recommends.  You will discover the MLE and that will tell you whether an order stat works and if so, which one.